# bool array which can get the value of its index from checkboxes

Tags: c#

I would like to make bool array which can get the value of its indexes from checkboxes' state ( `checked = true`, `unchecked = false`). because I would like to use that array to update my output. Please I need an example to make it

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Box1" Content="CheckBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Box2" Content="CheckBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Box3" Content="CheckBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,102,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Box4" Content="CheckBox4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />        
</Grid>
```

For example, if I have 4 checkboxes. Box1 and Box3 are true. the output of my array must be `{ true, false, true, false }`

Comment: You can't always get examples if you want to make your own applications. You should try it yourself and then show us what you have tried so far and what isn't working.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to learn? since this looks like WPF then it would be adviseable to bind the checkboxes to certain variables in your viewmodel and then shove those variables into an array. `INotifyPropertyChanged` will take care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of your checkboxes and then just select their checked value:

```
CheckBox[] chks = { Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4 };
bool[] result = chks.Select(x => x.Checked).ToArray();
```

or

```
bool[] result = Parent.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name)
      .Select(x => x.Checked).ToArray();
```